# gulpがうまくいかない: babel-dest が空のままになる

Tags: gulp

babel/の中のJSファイルを実行すると、下記のようにトランスパイルされているようなのですが
./babel-destの中身が空のままです。

・./babel-destのカレントディレクトリは、gulpfile.jsのあるフォルダと考えてよいでしょうか？
このファイルがjsフォルダの中にbabel-destフォルダと一緒に入っているのでこの指定で正しいはずですよね。

・出力先のフォルダ指定が間違っているならエラーが出るのではないのでしょうか？
うまくいかなくてもエラーが出ないなら切り分けができません。

・実行結果

```
js>gulp babelwatch
(node:6432) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
[20:14:15] Using gulpfile js\gulpfile.js
[20:14:15] Starting 'babelwatch'...
[20:14:15] Finished 'babelwatch' after 41 ms
[20:15:15] Starting 'babeltrance'...
[20:15:15] Finished 'babeltrance' after 50 ms
[20:17:18] Starting 'babeltrance'...
[20:17:18] Finished 'babeltrance' after 38 ms
[20:44:01] Starting 'babeltrance'...
[20:44:01] Finished 'babeltrance' after 91 ms
[20:45:22] Starting 'babeltrance'...
[20:45:23] Finished 'babeltrance' after 30 ms
```

・ソースコード抜粋

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');              
var postcssimport = require('postcss-import');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');  
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext'); 
var csswring = require('csswring');
var babel = require("gulp-babel");
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var csscomb = require('gulp-csscomb'); 
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');



gulp.task('babeltrance', function() {
  gulp.src('babel/*')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015'],
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./babel-dest'));
});

gulp.task('babelwatch', function() {
  gulp.watch('babel/*', ['babeltrance']); 
});

gulp.task('babel', ['babeltrance', 'babelwatch']);
~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ./babel-destのカレントディレクトリは、gulpfile.jsのあるフォルダと考えてよいでしょうか？

[gulp.dest](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpdestpath-options)のAPI上は、`options.cwd`のデフォルト値が`process.cwd()`となっているので、カレントディレクトリは、`gulpfile.js`のあるフォルダではなく、`gulp`を実行したフォルダになるようです。

> 出力先のフォルダ指定が間違っているならエラーが出るのではないのでしょうか？

[gulp.dest](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpdestpath-options)は`Folders that don't exist will be created.`とあるので、フォルダ指定が間違っていてフォルダが存在しない場合にも自動で作成するようです。

切り分けのためには、[gulp-debug](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-debug#gulp-debug-)というものがあるようです。
パイプラインの途中にはさめば、ストリームの状態をターミナルに出力してくれるようです。

---

補足です。

`gulp -h`によると、以下のように別ディレクトリの`gulpfile`を指定して実行する場合は、

```
gulp --gulpfile ./js/gulpfile.js babelwatch
```

自動的に、gulpfileが格納されているディレクトリにCWDを移動するようです。
そのため、`gulp.src`や`gulp.dest`内のパスは、`gulpfile`格納ディレクトリからの相対パスで書くと良いみたいです。

以下は、ヘルプの抜粋です。

```
--gulpfile, -f          Manually set path of gulpfile. Useful if you have
                          multiple gulpfiles. This will set the CWD to the
                          gulpfile directory as well.                   [文字列]
```

Comment: カレントディレクトリは、～\js>gulp babelwatchとコマンドプロンプトで実行しているのでjsフォルダがカレントディレクトリになっているのですね、これを実行したフォルダをカレントディレクトリとして、出力フォルダ内ないしはフォルダがなければ自動作成して出力するのですね、

Comment: それならうまくいっていればjsフォルダ内にbabel-destフォルダを自動的に作成するはずなのですね、

Comment: @nicomesecond さん、そうなると思います。

Comment: このようになりました、根本的におかしいのでしょうか？portfolio\js>gulp --gulpfile ./js/gulpfile babelwatch
[12:06:56] No gulpfile found

Comment: @nicomesecond さん、 `portfolio\js>`はシェルのカレントディレクトリが`js`ということではないでしょうか? もしそうであれば、`portfolio\js>gulp --gulpfile ./gulpfile babelwatch ` を実行すれば解決するかもしれません。

Comment: やってみましたがやはり変わりません。C:\Users\portfolio\js>gulp --gulpfile ./gulpfile babelwatch
[13:44:33] No gulpfile found

Comment: @nicomesecond さん すみません。私の記載が間違っていました。gulp --gulpfile ./gulpfile.js babelwatch か gulp --gulpfile ./js/gulpfile.js babelwatchのようにgulpfile.jsという実際のファイル名を--gulpfileに指定して実行してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。portfolio\js>gulp babelwatchだとなぜうまくいきませんでしょうか？\js>gulp --gulpfile ./gulpfile.js babelwatchこちらは、自分でこのガルプファイルを実行してと指定する方法なのですね。うまくいかない場合はとりあえずやってみますが、これをすると排出の際の問題が解決した理由がやはりわかりません。