# srcを変更したところなぜか反応しなくなりました。

Tags: gulp

[gulpがうまくいかない: babel-dest が空のままになる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/46811/gulp%e3%81%8c%e3%81%86%e3%81%be%e3%81%8f%e3%81%84%e3%81%8b%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-babel-dest-%e3%81%8c%e7%a9%ba%e3%81%ae%e3%81%be%e3%81%be%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8b)

の続き
前回の質問でうまくできたのですが、トランスパイルすJSファイルが、gulpファイルのカレントディレクトリにあるので下記のように、srcを変更したところなぜか反応しなくなりました。
相対パスの指定方法は間違っていないと思うのですがなぜ動かなくなったのでしょうか？

```
gulp.task('babeltrance', function() {
  gulp.src('./*.js')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015'],
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./babel-dest'));
});
```

・ディレクトリ構成

```
jsフォルダ
├
├─babel-dest
├─gulpfile.js
├─その他トランスパイルしたいjsファイル一覧
```

・下記のようにしたところうまくいきました。
第二引数の配列のような大かっこにタスクの名前を入れるのがひっすなのでしょうか？

```
gulp.task('babeltrance', function() {
  gulp.src('./*.js', ['babeltrance'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['es2015'],
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./babel-dest'));
});

gulp.task('babelwatch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./*.js', ['babeltrance']);
});

gulp.task('babel', ['babeltrance', 'babelwatch']);
```

Comment: 上記ディレクトリ構成であれば、ターミナルから`cd js`などして、カレントディレクトリをjsディレクトリにしている状態で、gulp babel(もしくは gulp babeltrance)を実行していれば、トランスパイルされると思います。

Comment: portfolio\js>gulp babelwatch
としても、jsファイルを変更しても反応がありません。

Comment: `babelwatch`の監視対象も右の `gulp.watch('./*.js', ['babeltrance']);`ように変更していますか?

Comment: このようになりました。portfolio\js>gulp.watch('./*.js', ['babeltrance']);
'gulp.watch' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。

Comment: すみません。記載があいまいでした。`gulpfile.js`内の`gulp.task('babelwatch', function() {`を定義している行の直下の`gulp.watch('babel/*', ['babeltrance']); `が`gulp.watch('./*.js', ['babeltrance']);`に修正されているか確認してください。

Comment: コメントを追加しました、ベストアンサーにしたいのですがどうすればいいですか？ありがとうございました。

Comment: 自己解決されたので、`下記のようにしたところうまくいきました`以降の部分を回答として追加し、ベストアンサーとして承認されると良いと思います。

Comment: ベストアンサーをお礼に差し上げたかったのですが、自己解決にしたほうがいいのですね。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

・下記のようにしたところうまくいきました。
第二引数が足りなかった。

```
gulp.task('babeltrance', function() {
gulp.src('./*.js', ['babeltrance'])
.pipe(plumber())
.pipe(babel({
presets: ['es2015'],
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./babel-dest'));
});

gulp.task('babelwatch', function() {
gulp.watch('./*.js', ['babeltrance']);
});

gulp.task('babel', ['babeltrance', 'babelwatch']);
```